# Add an autoincremental value with css counter

Tags: css

I want to add an incremental value through CSS, but apparently i am doing something wrong.

**HTML**

```
<ul role="menu" style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px;">
    <li id="Slideshow-13675338798500">
    <a class="slideshow-thumbnails-hidden" href="images/slideshow/slide-1.png" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
    <span class="thmubbutton"></span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li id="Slideshow-13675338798501">
    <a class="slideshow-thumbnails-hidden" href="images/slideshow/slide-2.png" role="menuitem" tabindex="1">
    <span class="thmubbutton"></span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li id="Slideshow-13675338798502">
    <a class="slideshow-thumbnails-hidden" href="images/slideshow/slide-3.png" role="menuitem" tabindex="2">
    <span class="thmubbutton"></span>
    </a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

---

**css**

```
span.thmubbutton{
    counter-increment: myIndex;
}

span.thmubbutton:before
{
content:counter(myIndex);
}
```

The output is `1 | 1 | 1`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgEgS/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset your counter to 0 before using it.

```
body {
  counter-reset: myIndex;   
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgEgS/1/

More info on counters here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Counters

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that CSS supports this natively. There's something called LESS (http://lesscss.org/) that does support increments. Try giving it a spin.

EDIT: nevermind... I believe I was wrong. Still, LESS is a good alternative as well. So I won't delete my answer ;)